# How can I separate an array of numbers into two clusters and return two subsets of corresponding indexes?

Tags: scikit-learn, subset, cluster-analysis

I have an array of scalar numbers, `pm`, and a list of indexes, `idx`, so `pm[idx]` is a subset of `pm`. How can I separate `pm[idx]` into **two clusters** (according to the Euclidean distance) and obtain **two sets of corresponding indexes** (ideally using **scikit-learn**)?

For example,

```
pm = array([0,1,2,3,4,100,105])
idx = [0,2,3,5,6]
```

How can I obtain the `idx1 = [0,2,3]` and `idx2 = [5,6]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you want to filter your data `pm` which can be easily done with your idx array. You can cluster your filtered data to obtain two groups.

Partition based clustering algorithms such as [k-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or [SingleLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering) can be perfectly applied. In `scikit-learn` you could use `/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering`.

As those clustering algorithms expects your data to have the features in columns and the instances as rows your need to reshape your data.

From the resulting cluster labels you can then create separate index arrays using a list comprehension. (didn't found a numpy function that does the same)

Your solution could look like the following:

```
cluster_algorithm = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2)
labels = cluster_algorithm.fit_predict(np.expand_dims(pm[idx], axis=-1))

print(labels)
>>> [1 1 1 0 0]

idx_labels = [np.where(labels == e)[0] for e in set(labels)]
idx_labels  # [array([3, 4], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: Just did! Sorry I forgot it before.